# Differentiating the spectral zeta function

Tags: zeta-functions

I need to figure out how $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \text{ln}\ \lambda_{k} = - \frac{d}{ds}\Big|_{s=0} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \lambda_{k}^{-s}$.

But, if I evaluate $- \frac{d}{ds}\Big|_{s=0} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \lambda_{k}^{-s}$, I get $- \sum_{k=1}^{n} \Big( \frac{d}{ds} \lambda_{k}^{-s} \Big) \Big|_{s=0}$, which becomes $ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \Big( s\ \lambda_{k}^{-s-1} \Big) \Big|_{s=0}$, and this is $0$.

Where am I making the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$
\lambda^{-s}_k=e^{-\log(\lambda_k)s}
$$

I'm sure you can take it from here

essentialy you are differentiating w.r.t. to $\lambda$ which is not what you want!